# Regular expression which accepts URL, IP address needs to accept file paths as well

Tags: c#

I have a regular expression that works for both IP addresses and FQDN. I need it to work for file paths as well.

I need help to modify this so that it accepts the file path as well. Please help me with this.

Below is my regular expression:

(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9].)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,63}$)

The regular expression should accept URLs with Http://, IP addresses, file paths. Anyone entry should yield a successful result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume a file path has to be the full path (e.g. "C:\path\to\file.txt"), then a simple regular expression for all three to match would be:

```
^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(http:\/\/.+)|(\w:\\.+)$
```

I'm simply combining 3 regular expressions to one by concatenating them with a pipe (regex-or), so the regular expression matches if one of them matches.

Comment: can we add "-" as well on this to accept the FQDN. The examples that need to pass are 1. \MT-SLO-X004\Share
2. \MT-SLO-X004.slo.mitratech.corp\Share
3. C:\temp\share

Comment: fqdn paths usually start with double-backslash "\\". so I would change the regex to `^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(http:\/\/.+)|((\w:)|(\\)\\.+)$` so it matches paths starting with a drive letter or with two backlashes.

Comment: The part for IP addresses worked really well but for FQDN, it did not work. My FQDN examples will be: 1. \\MT-SLO-X004\Share

Comment: hopefully, the "1." isn't part of your path ;) you can still separate the drive letter part and the fqdn part: `^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(http:\/\/.+)|(\w:\\.+)|(\\\\.+)$`

Comment: Thanks Simon, "1." is hilarious though :)